# Php MySQL Most Liked Query for last 100 Records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using this query:

```
SELECT * from likes GROUP BY url ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 6
```

to fetch most liked record from my table 'likes'. It is working perfect for fetching most liked content of all time.

But now to I want to select the 6 most liked record from the last 100 records.

What will be the query for it ?

Comment: can you show us the table structure of likes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from likes order by date desc limit 100) xx
Group by URL order by count(*) limit 6
```

Comment: its working but not ordering the data correctly .... means not showing the most liked first

Comment: Sorry, add DESC after Order by count(*)

Answer (score 2):

Obtain the primary keys of the last 100 entries and narrow your query to it. Probably extremely easy if you have auto-increment keys.

```
SELECT * from likes
  GROUP BY url 
  ORDER BY count(*) DESC 
  WHERE ID > MAX(ID)-100
  LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Are you sure that is working? Beside the syntax error, what if there is a record deleted and make your MAX(ID)-100 become faulty?

Comment: i have already figured out something resembling using serial no field in the table .... thanks for help :)